# Select distinct value count laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

I have an orders table where there is a status column.

I am trying to get the count of each status like this :

```
$pending = Order::where('status','=','pending')->count();
$active = Order::where('status','=','active')->count();
```

But this is not efficient as  am having to make one call for each status type.

How can I reduce number of queries ?

Answer (score 14):

To make an SQL request:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT `status_id`) FROM `dbname`.orders WHERE `user_id` = '2';
```

In Laravel you can try the following:

```
$user->orders()->distinct()->count(["status_id"]);
```

Comment: This deserves more upvotes. I see so many people doing this incorrectly -- this is the right way.

Answer (score 9):

You could try

```
$orders = Order::select(DB::raw('count(*) as order_count, status'))
  ->groupBy('status')
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the way you write ->

```
$users= DB::table('table_name')->distinct()->get(['column_name']);
$users_count = $users->count();
```

Comment: you save me alot with my query :
$DB::selectRaw('distinct field')->count();

and your answer is the only my answer for this whole bad day.